# React-native onpress into touchable open another model

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

i have this model into `react native` that name **LoginView.js**

```
    "use strict";
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry,TouchableOpacity, Text ,Button,Image,TextInput,PropTypes,StyleSheet,View,NavigatorIOS,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';


    class LoginView extends Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        HYGEX
                    </Text>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Username"
                            style={styles.formInput}
                             />
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Password"
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            style={styles.formInput1}
                             />

                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => this.move()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>

                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }

      move() {
          //here !!
        }
      }

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 30,
        marginTop: 65,
        alignItems: "stretch"
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    formInput: {
        height: 36,
        padding: 10,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 18,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#555555",
        borderRadius: 8,
        color: "#555555"
    },
    button: {
        height: 36,
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#555555",
        borderColor: "#555555",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginTop: 10,
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: "#ffffff",
        alignSelf: "center"
    },
});

module.exports = LoginView;
```

in this module i have method called `move`, when click into `touchable` move must open this module that name **test.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

i need this method in project its very important for me , if any one can tell me how to do this please !!

Note : iam beginner into react-native :)

**Edit**

i tried this code 
login.js

```
  "use strict";
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { AppRegistry,TouchableOpacity, Text ,Button,Image,TextInput,PropTypes,StyleSheet,View,NavigatorIOS,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';


    class LoginView extends Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>
                        HYGEX
                    </Text>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Username"
                            style={styles.formInput}
                             />
                        <TextInput
                            placeholder="Password"
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            style={styles.formInput1}
                             />

                    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => this.OnBUttonPress()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                   </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
 OnBUttonPress = () => {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'test'
      })
  }
    }

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 30,
        marginTop: 65,
        alignItems: "stretch"
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    formInput: {
        height: 36,
        padding: 10,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        flex: 1,
        fontSize: 18,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#555555",
        borderRadius: 8,
        color: "#555555"
    },
    button: {
        height: 36,
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#555555",
        borderColor: "#555555",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginTop: 10,
        justifyContent: "center"
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: "#ffffff",
        alignSelf: "center"
    },
});

module.exports = LoginView;

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => LoginView);
```

and this test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

export default class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '<Your welcome in Second Screen>',
      textBack: '<Tap to Go Back to First Screen>'
    }
  }
  OnBUttonPress = () => {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        id: 'WelcomeScreen'
      })
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.OnBUttonPress}>
              <Text>{this.state.textBack}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

i got this error 
**undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.props.navigator.push)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created a solution for multiple screen. so please read my code and implement as your requirement hope it will help you. Link here:
[Navigator sample](https://github.com/Anuj-786/NavigatorExapple)

if get any problem please ask me.

Comment: thank you very much for this project , i run it and its working , but i cannot apply for my case !  how to apply ???